# How to pass a boolean value from a Fragment to another fragment in android while click on a button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a button in my screen, I need to pass boolean value while click on the button.

Here while click on the button it starts a fragment and opens an another screen there I need to show only a button.

In the same way, the same button needs to show all the screen view If I navigate from an another fragment.

Can I able to send a boolean value along this and how it will be retrieved in another fragment?

```
   case R.id.tv_send:
        fragment = UserFragment.newInstance(this, mModel);
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user Argument to pass value fragment to fragment like this

**put your Boolean value**

```
fragment = UserFragment.newInstance(this, mModel);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("onPress",true);
fragment.setArguments(b);
```

**get your value for another fragment**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            boolean getValue = getArguments().getBoolean("onPress");
            
        }
```

Comment: In the same way after geting the data in a fragment, how can I send this value to an adapter.(boolean getValue = getArguments().getBoolean("onPress"); to an adapter